# Порядок действий метода JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

У меня есть класс. Мне нужно делать таких экземпляров много. Решил сделать файл типа `json` и залить туда все экземпляры класса. Но у этого класса есть конструктор  который изменяет некоторые значения переменных в зависимости от других. Получается указание этих "зависимых" переменных необязательно, только связные нужно указать. Как мне не записывать данные в файл тех переменных которые присвоят значение в конструкторе? Просто на насколько я знаю, нужно все переменные указывать в файле? Или я неправ?

Comment: Файлы, предназначенные для сериализации, не должны содержать логики. Из этого следует, что вам потребуется иметь два класса и конвертировать экземпляры одного в другой самостоятельно в коде

Comment: @АндрейNOP вы наверное не так поняли. С логикой я понял. У меня список наполняется за счёт этого файла.

Comment: [`[JsonIgnore]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm)?

Comment: Можно по подробнее?

Comment: Ссылку открывали?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Ой извините не заметил ту большую линию под текстом)) Щас почитаю

Comment: Можно в ответ, работает

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пометьте свойства, которые необходимо исключить из сериализации, атрибутом [`[JsonIgnore]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm)

Пример из документации:

Тип:

```
public class Account
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
}
```

Использование:

```
Account account = new Account
{
    FullName = "Joe User",
    EmailAddress = "joe@example.com",
    PasswordHash = "VHdlZXQgJ1F1aWNrc2lsdmVyJyB0byBASmFtZXNOSw=="
};

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(account);

Console.WriteLine(json);
// {"FullName":"Joe User","EmailAddress":"joe@example.com"}
```